# How to Migrate Core Data's Data to App Group's Data

Tags: swift, core-data, migration, ios-app-group, nspersistentcontainer

I just added `App Groups` to my app using this [StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476017/ios-today-extension-with-core-data). Unfortunately since the `defaultDirectoryURL` is changing, I can not fetch any of the old data I made before using the App Groups directory. I know the data is still there because when I switch back to using a regular `NSPersistentContainer` instead of the `GroupedPersistentContainer`, I can get the data.

How can I migrate my old data over to where I'm fetching the app group's data?

**Core Data code:**

```
class CoreDataManager {
    static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()
    private init() {}

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        var useCloudSync = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "useCloudSync")

        let containerToUse: NSPersistentContainer?
        if useCloudSync {
           containerToUse = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "App")
        } else {
            containerToUse = GroupedPersistentContainer(name: "App")
            let description = containerToUse!.persistentStoreDescriptions.first
            description?.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
      }

        guard let container = containerToUse, let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("Hey Listen! ###\(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description.")
        }
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in

      ...

      return container
   }
}
```

**GroupedPersistentContainer code:**

```
class GroupedPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
    enum URLStrings: String {
        case group = "group.App"
    }

    override class func defaultDirectoryURL() -> URL {
        let url = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: URLStrings.group.rawValue)

        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url!.path) {
            try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        return url!
    }
}
```

I haven't done this yet for my NSPersistentCloudKitContainer yet but it will follow the same format as this one.

Comment: I found this post to be helpful when doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191523/ios-11-how-to-migrate-existing-core-data-to-shared-app-group-for-use-in-extensi